# Join two DataFrames where the join key is different and only select some columns

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

What I would like to do is:

Join two DataFrames `A` and `B` using their respective `id` columns `a_id` and `b_id`. I want to select all columns from `A` and two specific columns from `B`

I tried something like what I put below with different quotation marks but still not working. I feel in pyspark, there should have a simple way to do this.

```python
A_B = A.join(B, A.id == B.id).select(A.*, B.b1, B.b2)
```

I know you could write

```python
A_B = sqlContext.sql("SELECT A.*, B.b1, B.b2 FROM A JOIN B ON A.a_id = B.b_id")
```

to do this but I would like to do it more like the pseudo code above.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your pseudocode is basically correct. This slightly modified version would work if the `id` column existed in both DataFrames:

```python
A_B = A.join(B, on="id").select("A.*", "B.b1", "B.b2")
```

From the docs for [`pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join):

> If `on` is a string or a list of strings indicating the name of the join
>   column(s), the column(s) must exist on both sides, and this performs
>   an equi-join.

Since the keys are different, you can just use `withColumn()` (or `withColumnRenamed()`) to created a column with the same name in both DataFrames:

```python
A_B = A.withColumn("id", col("a_id")).join(B.withColumn("id", col("b_id")), on="id")\
    .select("A.*", "B.b1", "B.b2")
```

If your DataFrames have long complicated names, you could also use `alias()` to make things easier:

```python
A_B = long_data_frame_name1.alias("A").withColumn("id", col("a_id"))\
    .join(long_data_frame_name2.alias("B").withColumn("id", col("b_id")), on="id")\
    .select("A.*", "B.b1", "B.b2")
```

Comment: Hi Pault, thank you for your help! However, the two id columns in my A and B tables have different names (e.g. a_id and b_id). I wonder if your approach will still work? I will do a check myself today but i feel like i tried the similar approach  in your format but not using on= and it seems not working. )

Comment: @ASU_TY I have updated the answer with a workaround for your issue.

Comment: I tried but it does not work for me. seems like the my console does not like this format("A.*", "B.b1", "B.b2") for some reasons

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the exact code you used and the full Traceback? Try to provide a [mcve] if possible. Also please include which version if Spark and python you are using.

Answer (score 4):

Try this solution:

```
A_B = A.join(B,col('B.id') == col('A.id')).select([col('A.'+xx) for xx in A.columns]
      + [col('B.other1'),col('B.other2')])
```

The below lines in `SELECT` played the trick of selecting all columns from A and 2 columns from Table B.

```
[col('a.'+xx) for xx in a.columns] : all columns in a

[col('b.other1'),col('b.other2')] : some columns of b
```

Comment: This is the right answer - you shouldn't have to rename columns to perform a join!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easier solution is just to join table A to table B with selected columns you want. here is a sample code to do this:

```
joined_tables = table_A.join(table_B.select('col1', 'col2', 'col3'), ['id'])
```

the code above join all columns from table_A and columns "col1", "col2", "col3" from table_B.

Comment: This only works if the join column is named 'id' in both tables.  The main issue here is that they are not both named 'id'.  The accepted answer has the issue nailed.