# Joins in pyspark different columns

Tags: pyspark

how do I join a pyspark dataframe on two different columns?

```
Cols df1: ID,DATE
cols df2: user,DATE

I want to Join df1.ID==df2.user and df1.DATE==df2.DATE
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Join two DataFrames where the join key is different and only select some columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49685474/join-two-dataframes-where-the-join-key-is-different-and-only-select-some-columns)

Answer (score 0):

```
Joindf = df1.join(df2.withColumnRenamed("ID","user"), ["ID","DATE"])
```

should do it for you.